# using laravel with apache and varnish

Tags: php, apache, laravel, varnish

So I have run into an issue that I am not able to find any resources on. I am trying to run laravel with apache and varnish. It is working fine with one exception, all of the urls are adding the port that apache is running on (8080). So when i go to the link:

```
http://localhost/
```

It works fine but all of the links on the site are showing up something like :

```
http://localhost:8080/about-us
```

I have varnish running on port 80 and apache running on port 8080. I am pretty sure that it is varnish causing the issue because when i run it with just apache on port 80 it works without adding in the port. Does anyone know how to get around it adding the port in there. I was not able to find any information on this issue through google.

Comment: Can you post your vcl backend definition? I'm pretty sure that Varnish is not the one to blame in this case but lavarel's default url rewritting

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP genius, but all web frameworks that I know of use the host header in the inbound request to generate non-relative links (side question: why are you rendering absolute URLs when the resource is on the same host in the first place?).

So, if in your VCL you're rewriting the request's or backend request's (bereq) Host header to localhost:8080 a la

```
set req.http.Host = "localhost:8080";
```

or

```
set bereq.http.Host = "localhost:8080";
```

or doing the same thing in apache, that's what's causing the issue. If it's not that, PHP is using the port the server is running on rather than the host header to construct URLs, which is almost universally undesirable behavior and is likely due to a misconfiguration on your part.